# Linear systems: Square root of input product

Tags: linear-systems, homework

Hi guys i'm studying signals and systems, and my professor ask us if this signal is linear or not

$$y(t) = \big[x(t − 1)x(t + 1)\big]^{\frac 12}$$

the fact that is in the form of $x\cdot x$ told me that that's not linear but the square root confuses me can you explain to me if this is linear or not?

Comment: Have you applied the *Standard Linearity Test* ?

Comment: yes but i can't undestand it

Comment: which square root?  the + one or the - one?

Comment: idk the exercise is written exactly this way

Comment: write down what you have applied, and lets which part you don't understand.

Comment: y=(ax(t-1)*ax(t+1))^(1/2) but then how i should continue ?

Comment: The *Linearity Test* : let $x_1(t)$ be an input, its output is $y_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ be another input, whose output is $y_2(t)$, then output for $x_3(t) = a\cdot x_1(t) + b \cdot x_2(t)$ must be  $y_3(t) = a\cdot y_1(t) + b \cdot y_2(t)$ , for all $a,b$  complex, for the system to be linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_1(t) = t^2$ and $x_2(t) = 1$. We have $$y_1(t) =\sqrt{(t-1)^2(t+1)^2}$$ $$y_2(t) = 1$$
Now let $x_3(t) = x_1(t) + x_2(t) = t^2 + 1$. Then we have $$y_3(t) = \sqrt{((t-1)^2 +1)((t+1)^2 +1)}$$ Obviously $$y_3(t) \not = y_1(t) + y_2(t)=\sqrt{(t-1)^2(t+1)^2} +1$$Therefore the system isn't linear.